# How to cast whole tab to chromecast when there is a cast sender available on page

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am adding support for Google Cast sender to a media player and it works as expected so far when casting media from player to chromecast by clicking on cast icon in player. But I am facing problem getting the whole website page/tab to cast to chromecast if the media player with sender app is present on the page. What happens is that when I start a new session from the cast extension button (i.e. click on cast extension button and then click one of the chromecast devices listed in the popup), the sessionListener in my media player's chrome sender app gets called with the session object, and active session is created between player and chromecast. But it takes away the opportunity to browse the website on cast device. Is it possible to cast whole tab when user initiates session by clicking on the cast extension icon even if a sender app is present on the page?

Comment: If the page is cast-enabled, it'll just cast that player. If it isn't cast-enabled, that's when you would be able to use tab casting. There might be some gimmicky way of doing it but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Thanks what I thought. But I have another use case where there are more than one senders on the page. In that case, how do I control which one receive the session?

Comment: Can you give an example of a page with more than one sender?

Comment: I have more than one player on the page, each having a sender app. So each can initiate cast to chromecast. But when session is initiated from cast extension, sessionListener of only one of the players gets called with session object.

Comment: Which player's sender app gets called? The first one?